# What is wrong in this PL/SQL program?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
declare
    p number:=371;
    x number;
    t number;
    sum number;
begin
    x:=p;
    while x>0 loop
        t:=x mod 10;
        sum:=sum+ t**3;
        x:=x/10;
    end loop;

    if (sum=p) then
        dbms_output.put_line(p||+' '||'an armstrong number');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi Subhash, You tell us! What do you expect? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is a keyword, just use another name for your variable, e.g. `mysum`.

```
declare
    p number:=371;
    x number;
    t number;
    mysum number;
begin
    x:=p;
    while x>0 loop
        t:=x mod 10;
        mysum:=mysum + t**3;
        x:=x/10;
    end loop;

    if (mysum=p) then
        dbms_output.put_line(p||+' '||'an armstrong number');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use keywords as name of variables. sum is a keyword in oracle so change variable name from sum to anything else.